# Cell reference out of range, Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Add Row

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I can not figure out why I keep getting this error when the script trigger runs:

[Screen shot of script error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDMlY.png)

I do not see the Add Row function anywhere in this script however it is in the appscript.json script.  Why am I getting this error and can I stop it?

Here is the script that runs on the trigger:

```html
// This script sends an e-mail to the rep when a pick up is complete, stamps the pick up data in the Report tab, and adds the job to the Check In tab

function pickUpEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // gets active spreadsheet
  var checkin = ss.getSheetByName("Check In"); //gets the Check In tab
  var app = ss.getSheetByName("App"); /// gets the App tab
  var report = ss.getSheetByName("Report"); //gets the Report tab
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var activeCell = app.getActiveCell(); //gets the active cell
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow(); //gets the row of the active cell
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn(); //gets the column of the active cell
  var job = app.getRange(activeRow, 1).getValue(); //gets the job #
  var jobRaw = app.getRange(activeRow,49).getDisplayValue(); //gets the raw job # (no EWR- prefix)
  var duration = app.getRange(activeRow,50).getDisplayValue() //gets the duration
  var date = app.getRange(activeRow, 3).getValue(); //gets the pick up date
  var contact = app.getRange(activeRow, 5).getValue(); //gets the contact
  var address = app.getRange(activeRow, 6).getValue(); //gets the address
  var rep = app.getRange(activeRow, 52).getValue(); // gets the rep
  var arrived = app.getRange(activeRow, 13).getDisplayValue(); //gets the arrival time
  var departed = app.getRange(activeRow, 14).getDisplayValue(); //gets the departed time
  var status = app.getRange(activeRow, 45).getDisplayValue(); //gets the pick up status
  var type = app.getRange(activeRow,53).getDisplayValue(); //gets the job type
 
  // Condition 1: if sheet is "App"
  if (activatedSheetName == "App") {
 
   
//Reps
    
if (rep == "MM") {
var repname = "Mike";
var repEmailAddress = "mmolter@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}
  
if (rep == "AG") {
var repname = "Ariel";
var repEmailAddress = "agalayda@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}

if (rep == "JM") {
var repname = "Joe";
var repEmailAddress = "mmolter@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}

if (rep == "CH" || rep =="CA") {
var repname = "Christina";
var repEmailAddress = "mmolter@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}
    
if (rep == "CK") {
var repname = "Caroline";
var repEmailAddress = "ckopko@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}    

if (rep == "TR") {
var repname = "Tom";
var repEmailAddress = "tom@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}

if (rep == "RP") {
var repname = "Robert";
var repEmailAddress = "rpoirier@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";}
  
  
  
  
  if (type == "Pick up") {var emailText = "picked up!";}
   if (type == "Delivery") {var emailText = "delivered!";}
 
    // Condition 2: if active column is 14 (N)
  if (activeColumn == 14) {

 
  
  // Paste to Check ins
 
    // Condition 3: if the status is "Completed"
    
  if (status == "Completed"){
  
  
  var inputRow = 1
  checkin.insertRowAfter(inputRow);
  var jobPaste = checkin.getRange(2,2).setValue(job);
  var datePaste = checkin.getRange(2,4).setValue(date);
  var repPaste = checkin.getRange(2,3).setValue(rep);
      
    
  // Paste to Pick up Report 
  report.insertRowAfter(inputRow);
 report.getRange(2,1).setValue(date); // Date
 report.getRange(2,2).setValue(job); //Job Number
 report.getRange(2,3).setValue(arrived); //Arrived
 report.getRange(2,4).setValue(departed); //Departed
 report.getRange(2,5).setValue(duration); //Status
 report.getRange(2,6).setValue(type); //Type
    
// this whole section below take photos from the AppSheet folder, searches for the job # in the Shared Company Photos, and either makes a new folder if not existing, or copies them to it
  var par_fdr = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B6lqZvelcxkeaWNZMmhKd0JDbjQ"); // Destination folder "Shared Company Photos"
  var fdr_name = jobRaw;

try {
  var newFdr = par_fdr.getFoldersByName(fdr_name).next();
  newFdr.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
catch(e) {
  var newFdr = par_fdr.createFolder(fdr_name);
  newFdr.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
 
  var search1  = "title contains ";
  var search2 = "'" + jobRaw + "'";
  var searchFor= search1+search2;
  var fileIds=[];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("16OkPTUa98pYPrDgJDATzRKTbq5h8_PcX").searchFiles(searchFor); // Source folder "App_Images"
  var URL= [];
  var link= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=";
 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
      
var copyFiles = file.makeCopy(jobRaw+"_on site",newFdr);
var fileId = copyFiles.getId();// To get FileId of the file
    fileIds.push(link+fileId+"<P>");

  //  file.setTrashed(true);
}  
  
  
   
var sig = "<p>Thank you,<p><b>The Road Crew<br><font color='#351C75'>Craters & Freighters</font color></b><br>333 Cedar Ave.<br>Middlesex, NJ 08846<br>732-563-9200-Tel<br>732-563-2221-Fax<br>";
  
    
  var message = 
"<font face='tahoma'>Hi "+ repname+","+ 
"<P>Your job<b> " +job+"</b> has been "+emailText+
"<p>"+contact+
"<br>"+address+
"<p><b>Arrived: </b>" +arrived+
"<br><b>Departed: </b>" +departed+
"<p><b>Time on site: </b>" +duration+
"<div id='pics' style='display: none;'><b>Pictures:</b><p>"+fileIds+
"</div>"+sig;

  
var bcc1 = "tom@cratersandfreightersnynj.com,mmolter@cratersandfreightersnynj.com,rpoirier@cratersandfreightersnynj.com,kkull@cratersandfreightersnynj.com";
var subject = job;
subject += " "+emailText;
  MailApp.sendEmail(repEmailAddress, subject + "", message, {htmlBody: message, name: 'C&F Road Crew', bcc: bcc1});
    
    
  // end of conditions 1,2,3
  }}}
  
  }
```

Here is the .json file:

```html
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Calendar",
      "serviceId": "calendar",
      "version": "v3"
    }],
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "AddRow",
      "libraryId": "164YbqtkyuQe4ObDI-oxi8pY7pvoXxYhJq_J5i51pcxtu0QrdlhHdj11_",
      "version": "2"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include a minimal example.  there is not enough information here to recreate the issue

Comment: There are several kinds of triggers. What kind of trigger is your question about?

Comment: I re-posted the question with supporting scripts sorry if it is too much to post

Comment: "Add Row" is the name of the Script project, not the name of a function. Which one is the code line 7 of checkInEmail file?

Comment: That 's just it, I can not find a Script Project Add Row.  Line 7 in the checkinemail script is var checkin = ss.getSheetByName("Check In"), //gets the Check In tab

Comment: Never mind I just realized that the script project which is named Add Row has three .gs  inside it.